# Store image in core data and Retina Display?

Tags: iphone, core-data, retina-display

I have an app that has hundreds of words with 3/4 images for each word.
I have 2 versions of each word one for iOS 3 and one for retina display.
I wish to save the images as data and connect them to the appropriate word so it will be easy to pull them later.

my question is -
how do i get the suitable size ?
its works great with the @2x wjen you get it from the app file system, but hoe does it supposed to work  when i get it from data ?

thanks 
shani

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Storing images in CoreData is a rather ill-advised idea. It will significantly bloat the size of the CoreData database and cause memory issues when you have faulted-in objects containing images. Instead you should write the images out to the filesystem and store the image path in CoreData.

Comment: Thanks. But what us the differens between having the images in the file system or in the data base? Isn't that the same? BTW each image is only about 8kbs.

Comment: If the image is in the filesystem, you can trivially unload it simply by dropping the UIImage reference. This means it only needs to stay loaded while it's being used. If the image is in CoreData, then you have to fault out the entire managed object to get rid of the image data. What's more, faulting in managed objects may end up loading the image data into memory even though you aren't trying to display the image.

Comment: But if you store the images on the filesystem, and they are user-generated images (photos, etc), isn't it easier to backup the data if it is all kept within core data? I am also thinking about this 2x issue with images stored in Core Data. Even if it's not the most desirable way to store images, sometimes it is necessary and we want to still be able to take advantage of retina display. It seems like the Core Data image will always be seem as non-retina and will always be scaled for retina display.

Comment: @JPK: Anything stored in the Documents folder (actually, anything stored outside of Library/Caches or the temp directory) are backed up, so there's nothing inherently easier about backing up data in CoreData.

Comment: @KevinBallard: I guess I was thinking about a custom backup like Dropbox, which I am just now implementing for my app. Doesn't that get a little sticky? I rather like just backing up and restoring just the one .sqlite file... Also, for core data, if you store a BLOB and use the ImageToDataTransformer, is that really so bad?

Comment: @JPK: If the images are rather small (e.g. tiny thumbnails) it's probably fine. If you're storing large images (e.g. screen size or larger), then it's probably a bad idea.

Comment: So far I have just saved small thumbnail images. But with all of the variations and different sizes needed for retina display, iPad, possible iPad retina at some point, different sizes I might want for the images in the future, I am just now creating a separate entity called, say, PersonImage, with one attribute 'image' and one relationship 'person', which will store the whole image (scaled if larger than 1024 in any direction). Since it is a separate entity it should not fault until it is needed, so better for memory that way. Bad idea?

Answer (score 4):

It's not quite unusual that you save the images with Core Data.
Take a look at the sample [iPhoneCoreDataRecipes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008913-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) to see how Apple stores the images in Core Data as Transformable Type.

Comment: I have seen that example. But how does helps me with the retina issue? Thanks, shani

Comment: you just save the retina ones in a separate field and use them

Comment: Hi, do you mean that the iOS will "Know" which file to use? itself?